# Fade all images other than the focused image - jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery

I have set up a responsive slider and would like to have all images other than the focused one to be transparent (opacity 50%). The focused image would be the image furthest to the left.

I have used the following plug-in for the slider:

http://matthewtoledo.com/creations/responsive-carousel/example/example-1.html

and have it implemented at:

http://www.schafrick.com/portfolio-clients-nike.html

My jQuery knowledge is very poor and I am unsure where to start. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

*Please keep in mind that when I say "focused" I am not referring to mousevents but am talking about the image furthest to the left.*

Comment: First, you need to figure out what is the active slide. Apparently you've got that figured out as you've got a navigation. Once you've got that, you'll need to reference the `li`'s with their `data-slide` attribute. I'd use jQuery to apply a class to only the active slide so that you can use css to to the opacity.

Comment: I understand that much but do not know how to do it. The slider is basically a ul contained with-in a masking div and the navigation (next/back) is shifting the ul to the left or right.

Comment: How did you get the numbers in the navigation? How do you determine what slide it's on in order to show "1/10" or "5/10"?

Comment: Please see my answer, it should work that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creator of the carousel already has some implementation:

[Example 2](http://matthewtoledo.com/creations/responsive-carousel/example/example-2.html)

The onShift-method is a setup parameter that takes a function. See: [Docu](https://github.com/mrbinky3000/responsive_carousel)
 
I adapted it for you:

```
$('#example').responsiveCarousel({
    // your setup tasks
    onShift: function (i) {
        i = Math.round(i);
        var $current = $('.slider-target li[data-slide=' + i + ']');
        $('.slider-target li[data-slide]').removeClass('current');
        $current.addClass('current');
    }
});
```

You can style the current frame with the .current class.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. The answer was right under my nose the whole time. Thanks!

Comment: How would I use the onShift-method to display the number of the images displayed and which image it is on (2/5)? The number count you see set up on my site is a little buggy, I had someone help me out with it.

Comment: "i+1" is the number you want to write on your number count. You can overwrite it also in the onShift-Method.
The other number is the "data-slide" attribute of the last element plus one. There may be an afterInit function or something in the docs you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

CSS

```
.slider-target img    {opacity:0.8;}
```

JQUERY

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.slider-target img', function () {
    $(this).css( "opacity", "1.0" );
}).on('mouseleave', '.slider-target img', function () {
    $(this).css( "opacity", "0.8" );
});
```

Comment: He's not talking about mouse events.

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery('.slider-target li').hover(function(e)
{
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').not(this).fadeTo(200, 0.5);
}, function()
{
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').not(this).fadeTo(200, 1);
});
```

this code should work if you included the jquery

Comment: "The focused image would be the image furthest to the left."

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work xD

```
$(document).ready(){

  $("img#gallery").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings("img").fadeTo("slow",0.5)
  },
  function(){
    $(this).siblings("img").fadeTo("slow",1)
  })


}
```

Just adapt the code to your need xD

Comment: Read the question. He didn't ask about `hover`.

Comment: Got it now, i think you shoul do something on the click event in that arrow button, determine which image is being moved to the left, and then change it's opacity